# Automatic exim4 ban ip

Tags: exim, brute-force-attacks

I would like to know if it is possible to automatically ban/filter an IP for few time in case of multiple authentication failure in exim4 server.

Comment: look up fail2ban

Answer (score 1):

fail2ban can watch logfiles of various programs, including exim and ban IPs which match a given pattern to block them for a given time using iptables.

Look for a fail2ban package in you operating system's package manager. Usually many examples are included in the package itself, you can also find some information in the [project's wiki page on exim](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Exim).

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used Config Server Firewall which has a bundled daemon (LFD) which works out of the box with Exim (along with several other services). https://configserver.com/cp/csf.html It's very popular on cPanel servers but there's no reason it shouldn't work on a bare server running exim, given that the log format is the same. Very easy to add exceptions and set the limit of time for how long the IP is blocked.